# Bash delete folder if not present in other folder

Tags: bash

imaging a folder structure like:

```
Peter
|- Cats
   |- Mini
   |- Maunz 
   |- Tippsi
|– Dogs
   |- Brutus

Eva
|- animals
   |- Mini
   |- Brutus
```

I'd like to delete all subfolders in `Peter/*/` if they not present in `Eva/animals/`  (Maunz and Tippsi).
This is what I have so far. It's working but it feels as my combination of loop and find is not the best solution:

```
for dir in ./Peter/*/*/
do
   dir=${dir%*/}
   if find './Eva/animals' -type d -name ${dir##*/} -exec false {} +
   then
      echo "${dir%*/} not found and deleted"
      rm -rf ${dir%*/}
    fi
done
```

For learning, can this code be optimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is good for finding files and directories recursively in a filesystem tree.
Based on your description and example, you probably don't need that.
If you want to check that some directory `foo` exists directly under `/some/path`,
it's much simpler and more efficient to use the `test` or `[` builtin.

There are some other minor issues in the posted code:

- It's a good practice (and often necessary) to double-quote variables in command parameters. For example instead of `rm -rf ${dir%*/}` write `rm -rf "${dir%*/}"`
- Instead of writing `${dir%*/}` 3 times, it would be better to store in a variable. In fact you did store the result of the first "call" in a variable, and since subsequent calls on the modified value will be the same, you could have used `$dir`.
- I think `dir=${dir%/}` is equivalent to `dir=${dir%*/}` but simpler.

Putting the above together, a cleaner, more efficient alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for dir in ./Peter/*/*/
do
    dir=${dir%/}
    name=${dir##*/}
    if ! [ -d "./Eva/animals/$name" ]
    then
        echo "$dir not found and deleted"
        rm -rf "$dir"
    fi
done
```